# Wpf/Silverlight gridview remove row blur effect

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, gridview

Removing first row and adding again as last.
So, when you delete a row from the GridView, how to apply effects to the line ?

```
ObservableCollection<Work> perWorks = new ObservableCollection<Work>();
void Timer2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region ListBox Remove And Effect / in Process
        if (works.Count > 1)
        {
            Work workTemp = works[0];

            works.RemoveAt(0); 
            works.Add(workTemp);
            DataContext = this; // BindGrid
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do here, could you elaborate and post your xaml? Why are you setting your datacontext in the timer delegate, what is the purpose of this? Tip if you want to change the presentation (visual representation) of your listbox, dump the template in blend or code.

Comment: You dont need xaml.. I just want to make effects when deleting a row .. It can be blur or opacity animation..

Comment: Someone is trying to help you, I suggest you act on their questions rather than telling *them* what they do and don't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to set the effect, you need to do. I think in your case, the GridView row are automatically generated. So when you modify the Datasource, the rows will change accordingly.

Deleting an item in the Datasource, is quit fast. It will be impossible to set an animation on row deletion or Unload since it will disapears from the list almost immediatly. 
What I suggest to do is:

1- Take a hold on the row to delete. (More easy in this case, since there is no loop).

2- Call a storyboard in xaml or code behind, as you wants...

3- Wait for the Storyboard.Completed event and then call the works.RemoveAt(...).

So you will have:

```
void Timer2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #region ListBox Remove And Effect / in Process
    if (works.Count > 1)
    {
        //Work workTemp = works[0];  //Don't know if really needed
          var fade = new DoubleAnimation()
          {
             From = 1,
             To = 0,
             Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
          };
       var item = //TheListBox.Items[];
       Storyboard.SetTarget(fade, item);
       Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fade,
                                    new PropertyPath(ListBoxItem.OpacityProperty));

       var sb = new Storyboard();
       sb.Children.Add(fade);
       sb.Completed += sb_Completed;
       sb.Begin(); 

    }
}


    void sb_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         works.RemoveAt(0); 
         //works.Add(workTemp);  //Don't know if really needed
         DataContext = this; // BindGrid --Is that correct to define the context each time you click ? :(
    }
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Doesnt work fade effect. I think problem is these lines..   var item = GridWaitCars.Items[0];
        Storyboard.SetTarget(fade, (DependencyObject)item);